# Representing data with textures

Tags: python, texturing, scripting

I'm looking for ways to illustrate a set of simulated swarm data in Blender. I am particularly interested in using the data to drive uv mappings of very many (about 10k) texture "particles". I also considered using an actual particle system, but as far as I can tell it seems you cannot explicitly control individual particles with python script. I'm also interested in the texture-based approach so I can try this visualization on arbitrary geometric surfaces.

Comment: Have you tried using boids?

Comment: You can generate images in blender, and use them as textures mapped to a plane. You can also use a frame handler to update the texture every frame, and for instance read data from an external source with your simulation data. You can use the image pixel location and RGBA color + transparency to represent 6 dimensional data (3D location + 3 other variables. You can also control the actual vertices of the plane, or the location of multiple simple objects representing your swarm. If you have sample data representing l10-20 frames (or time units) it shouldn't be too hard to use any of these.

Comment: @cegaton I am trying to visualize data from a client, not generate the simulation itself.